# Проблема с компиляцией приложения

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

Скомпилировал приложение с **pyqt** где используется сворачивание в трей(**QSystemTrayIcon**) при закрытие приложения.

```
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.tray_cb.isChecked():
            event.ignore()
            self.hide()
            self.tray_icon.showMessage(
                "Tray Program",
                "Application was minimized to Tray",
                QSystemTrayIcon.Information,
                2000
            )
```

При закрытие уже скомпилированного приложения сворачивание в трей не происходит, а приложение просто закрывается.

```
pyinstaller.exe --noconsole --onefile --icon=icon.ico main.py
```

Так же не устанавливается иконка в приложении, хоть установка иконки прописана и в коде.

Ссылка на репозиторий(не уверен нужен ли):
https://github.com/ashigaru0/project

Comment: Надо try icon подожить в каталог, например в ./data/icon.png и добавить ключ --add-data="data;data" pyinstaller.exe -w -F --noconsole -i "icon.ico" --add-data="data;data" main.py - пробуйте

Comment: Ещё рекомендую посмотреть такой вариант хранения картинок https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293422/pyqt4-setwindowicon-from-base64

Comment: Ещё в Вашем проекте нет icon.png

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. UPD: Приложение не сворачивалось в трей из-за отсутствия иконки

Comment: Я проделал с base64 внутри файла, без внешних иконок - тоже прокатило, и ещё у Вас ошибка:         quit_action.triggered.connect(qApp.quit) заменить на quit_action.triggered.connect(QApplication.quit) иначе из трея не выходит и висит в памяти

Comment: Ещё в догонку - установите upx.exe - файл EXE мегабайт на 6.5 будет меньше